Is the sequence $\sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^n\cos^ni}$ convergent?
Does this sequence of number converge? If yes, what is its limit?
$$a_n=\sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^n\cos^ni}$$
We know that $\displaystyle\sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^n\cos^2i}$ is much simpler. This is an advanced problem our teacher has given to us. I tried to check the values of each term and it seems that $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{2k}=1$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{2k-1}=-1$, but some culculators show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$ (without a step-by-step solution though).

From a simple graph of this, it appears that the $a_{2k-1}$ case is predominantly negative but occasionally positive (one such location near $2k-1=1063$), so I would recommend looking for a way to show that this case does not converge.

Examining $a_{m,n} = \sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^n \cos^m(i)}$, it appears that for even $m$, $a_{m,n} = 2^{-m/n}(C+Kn +\text{trig})^{1/n}$, whereas for odd $m$, $a_{m,n} = 2^{-m/n}(C+\text{trig})^{1/n}$. That is, the even subsequences have something that is, essentially, $(an+b)^{1/n}$, which should converge to $1$, but the odd ones should oscillate. My guess is that this is because the even-degree Chebyshev polynomials have a constant, $1$, which when summed gives $n$, whereas the odd-degree ones do not.

Hmm, after playing around with it more, I think there is a clear pattern. I might turn this into an answer later, but I would encourage you to try to prove the claims in my previous comment, evaluate the limits $(C+Kn + \text{trig})^{1/n}$ and $(C+\text{trig})^{1/n}$, and then show the series have these forms. That should do it.
